# Bibtex style for Proceedings of Royal Society A

Tags: bibtex

Is there any bibtex style file available which is suitable for [Proceedings of Royal Society A](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/site/misc/preparing-your-article.xhtml#question3) journals?

Comment: I thing you should ask them! Because they provide no information in their webpage, except for an email for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible through `RS.bst` file which is available at
http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/author-information

Use the following in the main text file:

```
\bibliographystyle{RS} % RS.bst is the bibtex style you have to download it 

\bibliography{referncefile} % referencefile.bib is the collection of references in a separate bib file
```